# Centering CSS divs that are floated

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a practice exercise where I'm trying to re-create this: https://ibb.co/Nx48VbD

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row-1 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1178px;
  height: 146px;
  margin: 96px auto 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  right: 12px;
}

.row-2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.b1 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 346px;
  height: 248px;
  margin-top: 24px;
  float: left;
}

.b1:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-right: 90px;
}

.b1:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 46px;
}

.b1:nth-of-type(3) {
  bottom: 12px;
  right: 12px;
}

.row-3 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1188px;
  height: 326px;
  margin: 24px auto;
  border-radius: 36px;
}

.b2 {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 202px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  float: left;
}

.b2:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 726px;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.b2:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 438px;
}

.b3 {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 202px;
  margin-top: 24px;
  float: left;
}

.b3:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 436px;
  margin-right: 84px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.b3:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 666px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-1"></div>
<div class="row-2">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b1"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="row-3"></div>
<div class="row-4">
  <div class="b2"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div class="row-5">
  <div class="b3"></div>
  <div class="b3"></div>
</div>
```

I was able to get the 1st and 3rd rows to center by using margin: 0 auto;. However, when I try this on the 2nd, 4th, and 5th rows, it doesn't seem to work. How can I center them like how it is shown in the image?

Also, I have background-color: gray; border: 1px solid black; in a lot of places. Is there a way I could do this DRY-er?

I also have a lot of margin-top margin-bottoms since every box has a border of 12px. Is there a way I could do this DRY-er as well?

Note: This exercise is supposed to be done without using flexbox or css grid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of floats on `.b1`

Setting them to equal width using calc and then setting text-align: center on the row-2 should do it

```css
.row-2{
  text-align: center;
}

.b1{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: calc(100%/3 - 10px);
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-2">
    <div class="b1"></div>
    <div class="b1"></div>
    <div class="b1"></div>
</div>
```

if you want to make your colors/borders DRY-er I'd recommend learning SASS/SCSS then you can make use of variables and mixins

https://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to solve a problem for you, this is not an exact example. This is a hint that you would pay attention to `flex`

Flex does not cancel margins or padding, there are also rules for flex children. Which can indicate without margins where to locate and how much space to occupy in the container .. There are a lot of interesting rules

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row-1 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1178px;
  height: 146px;
}

.row-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.b1 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 346px;
  height: 248px;
}

.row-3 {
  background-color: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 1188px;
  height: 326px;
  border-radius: 36px;
}

.row-4 {
  display: flex;
}

.row-5 {
  display: flex;
}

.b2 {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 202px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.b2:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 726px;
}

.b2:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 438px;
}

.b3 {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 202px;
}

.b3:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 436px;
  border-radius: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="row-1">row-1</div>
  <div class="row-2">
    <div class="b1">b1 in row-2</div>
    <div class="b1">b1 in row-2</div>
    <div class="b1">b1 in row-2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-3">row-3</div>
  <div class="row-4">
    <div class="b2">b2 in row-4</div>
    <div class="b2">b2 in row-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-5">
    <div class="b3">b3 in row-5</div>
    <div class="b3">b3 in row-5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Note: This exercise is supposed to be done without using flexbox or css grid."_

Comment: Now 21st century. I want to remind ... And this is a better solution than float

Answer (score 0):

From your image, it does not seem like you actually want any of your rows to float. What float does is take your element out of the flow of the document and put them in a new detached flow that is only affected by other floating elements in the same context.

It seems like what you want to have is all the rows centered with the same width, one after the other and the elements inside the rows floated.

Instead of what you currently have for `row-2` I would do the following:

```
.row-2, .row-4, .row-5 {
   width: 1178px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle that shows the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/fvzaujob/1/

On a side note, a more widely used solution nowadays is using flex or grids instead of float to control the flow of elements in a document, since it gives you more control over the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate column follow this code. No need to set any margin space for every column . You can adjust the container width based on your need. **No Bootstrap and flexbox used in this code**. I hope this answer will be helpful.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1178px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row-3 {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.row-1 {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 50px 0 0;
}

.col-4 {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 32.26%;
    height: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0;
}

.row:before,
.row:after,
{
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.row {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 140px;
}

.col-4:first-child,
.col-9:first-child,
.col-3:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.col-4,
.col-9,
.col-3 {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 1.6%;
    height: 140px;
}

.col-9 {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.col-3 {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 38.26%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-1"></div>
  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-4"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row row-3"></div>
  
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```